# I have deployed flask API on IIS. It is working fine without NLTK package

Tags: python, nltk

If I import NLTK and try to use nltk.pos_tag(text_token) getting error. Seems python is not accessing NLTK from IIS.
I have already installed NLTK in python.

This is my code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('E://RequirementValidation')
from flask import Flask
from flask import request,jsonify
from bot.mainFile import  main1
from flask import render_template
import pandas as pd
import nltk
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/test', methods=['GET','POST'])
def my_form_post():
    #df= pd.DataFrame(["1","xxxxx"])`enter code here`
    text_token = nltk.word_tokenize(" my name is XXXX") 
    text_pos = nltk.pos_tag(text_token)
    return "sandeep"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0',port=8084)
```

Comment: What is the error you get? What's NLTK's installation location? (Type `import nltk; nltk` in an interactive Python session to find out the latter.)

Comment: i'm getting this error- "Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application."
Later I tried with django, I was facing issue "english.pickle" not found "lookup error" . I appended path for NLTK in my code and it is running fine. Since Flask is very easy so i want my api in flask only. It is running on cmd locally . But on IIS seems some issue with nltk, not getting exact error also.

Comment: `nltk.download('punkt')`

Comment: Flask on IIS? why?!

Comment: I have same kind of error with python script on IIS, have you found solution in meantime?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
import nltk 
nltk.data.path.append('C:/Users/***/AppData/Roaming/nltk_data/')
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.